# Eclipse (on mac) bug: inserting html between 2php tags impossible

Tags: php, html, eclipse, macos, eclipse-pdt

I'm facing a really annoying and blocking issue with Eclipse indigo (latest update) on my Mac.
Every time I try to type an HTML tag between 2 PHP tags the editor start bugging, I can't type in anything and basicaly I have to close the file.

Example of what I initate the bug:

`<?php if():?>
<fieldset></fieldset> (when typing this rown in between the 2 php tags)
<?php endif;?>`

I found this bug described on Eclipse website under 2 diffents bug ids:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359473
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350139

Did anyone faced this issue and found a workaround?
The only option left I can see is to install an older version of Eclipse.

Thanks,

Comment: Newer version 3.0.2 having new bugs is available at http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

Comment: This is happening on my Window machine too. Eclipse 3.7.1, PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77--84. Driving me insane!

Comment: do you have a 64bit pc? i read a lot of people has this problem on 64bit pc, maybe these two things are related

Comment: Solved with the latest Eclipse version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a compromise if your preference is Eclipse but Netbeans doesn't have this problem. You could also print your HTML from PHP instead of dropping out of PHP.

Comment: I won't change my way of coding because of a bug in eclipse. With the latest version I'm not facing this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a previous comment, issue had been solved by installing the latest release of Eclipse. I still don't know what exactly was causin the issue.